# Can't show Rich Media message in splash screen

Tags: android, firebase, pushwoosh

I successfully integrated pushwoosh in my app.I can receive push notification from pushwoosh's pannel. I have one problem ,In my splashScreen I try to send some http request when app was starting and when Http request starting pushwoosh's Rich Media  not showing.
Is a any way to check ,when Rich Media 's message has showed

Comment: Can you show any of your code?

Comment: Yes sure, But I am using Handler with 500 uptimeMillis  @JakeSteam

Comment: pushwoosh's rich media message automatically hidden when second Activity was started @JakeSteam